# When will local reference be cleared if not created inside native method?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I initialized a JavaVM by `CreateJavaVM` and got a `JNIEnv` by `jvm->GetEnv`, and created some local references by `FindClass`, `NewObject` or `CallObjectMethod` etc.

In the JNI online doc, it says

> In most cases, the programmer should rely on the VM to free all local references after the native method returns.

I was wondering will those local references be cleared automatically, or should I clear them manually by `DeleteLocalRef` or `PopLocalFrame`?

Comment: In most cases you can rely in what your quotation says to do in most cases. If you allocate large numbers of local references you should look at push/popping local frames as the simplest way to manage them.

Answer (score -2):

Your local references will be freed and garbage collected automatically when the JNI function call return. So, we don't have to manually free local references in JNI call most of the time.

In a special circumstance, if there are a large number of local references in your JNI call, you should delete the references manually by `DeleteLocalRef` after you finish use them and no longer require.

There is an function call in JNI to ensure the number of local reference you can create, `EnsureLocalCapacity`.

Cited from the [JNI document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local).

> JDK/JRE 1.1 provides the DeleteLocalRef function above so that programmers can manually delete local references. For example, if native code iterates through a potentially large array of objects and uses one element in each iteration, it is a good practice to delete the local reference to the no-longer-used array element before a new local reference is created in the next iteration.

For the global references, the garbage collector and JVM don't do much work for us, we should always keep track and release them manually, otherwise it will cause memory leak.

For more information about best practices for using JNI, I would suggest this [developerworks article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/).

Comment: They will be *dereferenced* automatically when the JNI method returns; they will be garbage-collected when and if the garbage-collector decides to do so, and not before. For global references, the garbage-collector and JVM don't do *any* work for us.